# Is this match in the 2019 Taça de Macau, the most goals scored by a losing team?

Tags: football

The losing team, Hang Sai, scored 18 goals in this match (deliberately of course).
Is it the world record of most goals scored by a losing team?

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ka_I_21%E2%80%9318_Hang_Sai

Comment: Including penalty shootout?

Comment: No, of course not.

Comment: Then there's probably no other match in professional football with a score that high (on both ends). The record is 19 goals when you include penalties.

Answer (score -1):

There is this game in the second division in Trinidad and Tobago where [**WASA Clean and White wins 15 goals to 13 against Crab Connection**](http://www.rsssf.com/tablest/trin04.html).
Apart from this game I've never seen a team lose by scoring more than 9 goals.

Comment: Fascinating stuff, but it doesn't beat the 18 asked for in the question.